# error: cannot find symbol?

Tags: java

Hey I don't understand why this code is wrong I'm pretty sure I did everything right logic wise. I think its the case sensitive am I right?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Letgoshop
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter item: ");
String name = input.nextline();

System.out.println("Enter Price: ");
double price = input.nextdouble();

System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
int m = input.nextint();

System.out.print("You owe $" + m*price + " for " + m + " " +    name.toUpperCase() +"(S)");   

}
}
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive. `nextline(); -> nextLine();`, `nextdouble(); -> nextDouble()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're misspelling the `Scanner` method names, they should be:

```
System.out.println("Enter item: ");
String name = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter Price: ");
double price = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
int m = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct these methods names of `Scanner` class:

```
 input.nextline();
 ...
 input.nextdouble();
 ...
 input.nextint();
```

With writing them with the right name because java is case sensitive:

```
 input.nextLine();
 ...
 input.nextDouble();
 ...
 input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is case sensitive, you misspelling the method.
nextline() --> nextLine() 
nextdouble() -> nextDouble()

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Letgoshop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter item: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Price: ");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
        int m = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("You owe $" + m * price + " for " + m + " " + name.toUpperCase() + "(S)");

    } 
}
```